# How do I deep copy a list

Tags: python

How to make a copy of a list ?
I have code somewhat as follows :

```
l = ['1','2','3']
l.pop()

for (x in somerange):
    a = []
    a = l
    a.append("something")
```

But I don't want the contents of a to reflect in l.
How do I make a copy of l and assign it to a.

Comment: Python already has a builtin priority queue class: http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the body?

Comment: @Marcin: Don't edit "duplicate" into the title; that's put there by the system *after* it's closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Wooble Try removing it.

Comment: @Marcin: thegrinner got to it first.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a shallow copy of a list (which doesn't copy any contained lists, just references them) by doing this:

```
a = l[:]
```

or

```
import copy
a = copy.copy(l)
```

The copy module also has a deepcopy function which duplicates any contained mutable objects:

```
import copy
a = copy.deepcopy(l)
```

Hope that helps!